# Get ancestor onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm writing script which should find onclick attributes on any ancestor.

For example when I click on span.tabIdent I want get anchor onclick (I trigger it later)

HTML:

```
<a class="t3 lin tab-B" rel="#categoriesLinux" rev="lin" onclick="changeTab()">
  <span class="tabLeft" style=""></span>
  <span class="tabCenter" style="">
    <span class="tabIdent" style=""></span>
  </span>
  <span class="tabRight"></span>
</a>
```

JS:

```
var foo, 
    foo2,
    przodek,
    parentsCount = jQuery(that).parents().length,
    przodek = jQuery(that); //it's ok here

for(var ii=0; ii<parentsCount; ii++){
  przodek = jQuery(przodek).parent();
  foo = jQuery(przodek).prop('nodeName'),
  foo2 = jQuery(foo).attr('onlick');
  console.log(foo+' : '+foo2);
}
```

It return everywhere 'undefined'.
What is wrong with this ?

Comment: OK I've got It.
    dupa2 = jQuery(dupa).attr('onlick');
should be
    dupa2 = jQuery(przodek).attr('onlick');
What a shame. Thanks everybody.

Comment: @can you write that as an answer, please?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is definitely not helpful to future visitors

Comment: Is your code run inside Document ready or you have load them first then jQuery, if Not fix it.

Comment: Do you have console it in Firebug. If you use Debugging in Firebug then you can solve it yourself.

Comment: @JanDvorak I can't do this:
Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.

Answer (score 2):

You make a spelling error: `onlick` is not `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this...

```
$('.tabIndent').on('click', function() {
   var anchor = $(this).closest('a');

   console.log(anchor.prop('nodeName') + ' : ' + anchor.prop('onclick'));
});
```

Comment: I can't. This is only example. It should work for any page and elements. Not only this .tabIndent and anchor

Comment: Can you use data- tags to highlight the element you're using? Such as data-parent='a' on the span?

Comment: I cant't touch HTML. I write only script.